# Inserted HTML Not Responding to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

Whenever I use ajax to fetch new HTML from my server, then jQuery to modify the current HTML on my page, the new jQuery that is inserted does not respond to the javascript I have on my page.

For example, when I have this code:

```
<td id="is_admin_14">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i>
    <a class="subtle-link demote-member" href="demote-link"> <small>Demote</small></a>
</td>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function($) {

  function updateAdminStatus(url) {
    $.post(url, function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            var cell = $('#is_admin_'+data.member_pk);
            cell.html(data.html)
        }).fail(function() {
            // handle unexpected error here
            alert("error");
        });
  }

  $('.promote-member, .demote-member').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        updateAdminStatus($(this).attr('href'));
  });

});
</script>
```

and I click the .demote-member link, the ajax post is sent, I get the html back, and I repopulate the table cell with the returned html, which is the following:

```
<td id="is_admin_14">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle danger"></i>
    <a onclick="return false;" class="subtle-link promote-studio-member" href="promote-link"><small>Promote</small></a>
</td>
```

Now when I click the promote-studio-member link, without reloading the page, the jQuery is entirely ignored, and it tries to navigate to the href link, as it would if there was no jQuery provided. I cannot keep promoting and demoting to my heart's desire on the same page. (Also note that I even tried to put an `onclick='return false;'` in there, but the link still fires.)

Why is this happening, and is there any way to make the new html respond to the jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click",".promote-member, .demote-member ,.promote-studio-member",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    updateAdminStatus($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Since the html is being added to the DOM dynamically, you need to handle it using [**Event Delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery

Comment: Not doing it for me. Links are always firing

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks for the code and brief explanation.

Comment: Reducing overhead, and is easier to implement. Sweet. Make sure you attach the event handler to an element the is not updated after loading; eg. body or document.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding static html element before `.promote-member, .demote-member`

for eg if `<div id="container">` is static element always added ..

Try this

```
$("#container").on("click",".promote-member, .demote-member",function(){

alert("Test");

});
```

Comment: Links are still firing after the ajax call

Comment: The reason this didn't work was because the container I added was still wiped out by the html switch, since I modify the entire html between the `<td>` tags. If I had added a class to my <td> tag and used that as a container I assume this would have worked just the same as @sanki's answer. Thanks for the help.